# How to combine multiple `if` clauses with repeating condition and assignment patterns into a single generic one?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm dealing with multiple (about 10) `if` clauses, each clause targeting a different object property ... something like shown with the next provided example code ...

```
if (typeof credentials.useraa !== 'undefined') {
  data.useraa = credentials.useraa
}
if (typeof credentials.userac !== 'undefined') {
  data.userac = credentials.userac
}
if (typeof credentials.userad !== 'undefined') {
  data.userad = credentials.userad
}
```

How can one achieve the same result with less repeating code in a shorter (and maybe more generic/expressive) way, like combining the `if` clauses into a single one if that was a possible approach to start with.

Comment: Almost every programing language has boolean operators that are meant to be used in if. Try `&&` and `||`.

Comment: I tried them but in my case will not make the desirable output.

Comment: The danger with `||` and `&&` is that it evaluates things as truthy/falsy. If OP wants to target `undefined` specifically but leave empty strings or number `0` alone, then `||` or `&&` will not cut it.

Comment: I'd replace the ifs with a loop, iterate `credentials`, and if the item is not `undefined` create `data[item]`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's better suited on CodeReview since it works. https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Something like `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(credentials)) {data[key] = value;}`. If `credentials` actually can contain `undefined` values, you can check the values before assigning into `data`. It's also possible to do like `Object.assign(data, credentials);`.

Comment: I actually wonder what about how the OP present the problem is opinion based. Obviously the OP is aware of writing 10 times an `if` clause with a repeating pattern is not such a good idea. Thats why the OP asks for help, already pointing into the only possible (non opinionated) direction ... _"I am wondering if I can make them in more comprehensive and elegant way like combining all of them in one?"_. (The OP could have skipped/canceled "elegant" though in order to not make an opinionated impression at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maybe already obvious approach was to iterate an array of property names / `key`s and assign only the property values of `credentials` (source object) as entries (key-value pairs) to `data` (target object) which are not undefined.

One can take this approach one step further and *implement it as a **reusable** function* by taking advantage of the [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#parameters) parameter which almost every array method does support.

An implementation then might look like the next provided example code ...

```js
function assignDefinedValueToBoundTarget(key) {
  const { source, target } = this;
  const value = source[key];

  if (typeof value !== 'undefined') {
    target[key] = value;
  }
}

const credentials = {
  useraa: 'userAa',
  // userab: 'userAb',
  userac: 'userAc',
  userad: 'userAd',
};
const data = {};

console.log({ data });

['useraa', 'userab', 'userac', 'userad']
  .forEach(assignDefinedValueToBoundTarget, {
    source: credentials,
    target: data
  });

console.log({ data });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... or in terms of ***"defined equals an [own property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)"*** regardless of the actual property value ...

```js
function assignOwnPropertyValueToBoundTarget(key) {
  const { source, target } = this;

  if (source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    target[key] = source[key];
  }
}

const credentials = {
  useraa: 'userAa',
  userab: undefined,
  userac: 'userAc',
  userad: null,
};
const data = {};

console.log({ data });

['useraa', 'userab', 'userac', 'userad', 'userae']
  .forEach(assignOwnPropertyValueToBoundTarget, {
    source: credentials,
    target: data
  });

console.log({ data });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```